# Rails Console Crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, console, rails-console

When I load up my Rails Console, I get the following error

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
/Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `initialize': No such file or directory -  (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `open'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/magic-file.rb:7:in `open'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/input-method.rb:77:in `initialize'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:82:in `new'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:82:in `initialize'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:99:in `new'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:99:in `initialize'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:56:in `new'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:56:in `start'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

Here's the Gemfile for those asking. There isn't an .irbrc file...

```
gem 'rabl'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'cgi-spa'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

I'm using a Mac OS.X Version 10.7.3.

Comment: People are going to need more information in order to help you.

Comment: Show your `.irbrc` file and `Gemfile`.

Comment: Is it output of simple `rails c` command (without flags)?

Comment: Yes, this is the output for rails console. There isn't an .irbrc file.

Comment: show us the output of `head /Users/nataliamurashev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/magic-file.rb`

Comment: did you open the rails console with bundle exec? 
`bundle exec rails c`

Comment: Maybe try upgrading rvm to a higher patch level of 1.9.3?  Should be up to p429 now.

Comment: IRB wants to run some script/file which it cannot find. It looks like you are starting rails console with extra argument after environment, empty string ("") to be precise - hence two spaces before Errno instead of a filename. When you run `rails console development foo` you get same error but with one space and the "foo": `.../magic-file.rb:7:in 'initialize': No such file or directory - foo (Errno::ENOENT)`. I can reproduce you error by running `rails console development ""`. So how do you start rails console exactly? Btw, IRB should be smart enough to ignore empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but how about updating RVM, ruby and rails to the latest versions.
At the time of this writing Ruby is at version 2.0.0-p195.
RVM will allow you to run multiple version of ruby so you can also try the latest version of 1.9.3 which is Ruby 1.9.3-p429

See this link for instructions on getting up to date.
http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html